# SHOPIFY: JS Cookie Set in the Product page but not retrieve on cart page

Tags: jquery, cookies, shopify, setcookie, jquery-cookie

Actually, I want to store the latest product URL in the cookie, so If the user clicks on the CONTINUE SHOPPING button on the cart page, it redirects to the last access product page. If the cookie has the value then the user redirects otherwise, it redirects to the SHOP page.

**Here is the code, that I applied.**

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-cookie/1.4.1/jquery.cookie.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("products") > -1) {
      var latestProductUrl = window. location.href; 
      $.cookie("lastProductUrl", latestProductUrl);
      console.log('Success '+$.cookie("lastProductUrl"));
    }
    else if(window.location.href.indexOf("cart") > -1){
        console.log('here:'+$.cookie("lastProductUrl"));
    }
   
 </script>
```

It shows me in the console.
Success: defined and retrieved.
Here: Undefined.

Comment: Does this answer your question, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1458724/how-do-i-set-unset-a-cookie-with-jquery ?

Comment: Nope. 
As you can see, I am using a different cookie library.

and when I use the reference syntax and method. It shows me an error of 
Cookies is not defined

Comment: As far as I  read yesterday. The jquery that library is old and no longer maintained. So don't use this library. Go to latest version.

Comment: This is the latest version of the JS library that I am using 3.7.x
and jQuery-cookie/1.4.1

Will you please let me know the latest version or any other library?

Comment: I have explained in the answer. Read that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As **$.cookie** is not a part of jQuery library and for using **$.cookie**, you need a **[jquery-cookie](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie)**.

Don't use this plugin. It is **deprecated now** and it is supersededby [JS Cookie](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie). You can read on GitHub repository of jquery-cookie plugin that it is superseded by JS Cookie. **JS Cookie is a Javascript API** for handling browser cookies.

Here is the updated code using JS Cookie:-

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.7.0.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/js-cookie@3.0.5/dist/js.cookie.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("products") > -1) {
      var latestProductUrl = window. location.href; 
      Cookies.set("lastProductUrl", latestProductUrl);
      console.log('Success '+Cookies.get("lastProductUrl"));
    }
    else if(window.location.href.indexOf("cart") > -1){
        console.log('here:'+Cookies.get("lastProductUrl"));
    }
 </script>
```

Note that:-

- As I am using JS Cookie so the **CDN** is changed.
- The **syntax** for storing and retrieving the cookie value is also changed.

You can read about it more in the JS Cookie GitHub repository. Hope it will be helpful.

Comment: It still showing 
Cookies is not defined


Here is the website product URL.
https://www.simplybeach.com/products/makro-notion-ruched-side-bikini-pant-cream-aubergine

Comment: I think cdn is missing in the answer. let me add

Comment: @Boyka I have put the cdn on the answer. Now try that.

Comment: @Boyka My pleasure. If its helpul., mark this answer correct for future visitors.